# Is there a way to open a specific book in iBooks?

Tags: ios, ibooks

I am developing an application that could have a potential companion reference in the form of an ePub/PDF/iBook.  There's a scheme for opening iBooks from your application, but is there a known way to open a specific book (not import the book, rather open an existing book in the app)?  Bonus points: open a specific location in the given ePub/PDF/iBook?

I have scoured Google looking for this answer but only turn up the scheme: only one piece of the puzzle.

Comment: I need this too.  Did you ever figure out how to do it?

Comment: @JoshuaFrank No, I have not.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3**

From the [iBooks Author support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202929) :

> To link to another book in iBooks, you need to know the book’s asset
>   ID. Find a book’s asset ID by going to its iTunes Preview webpage and
>   checking the number in its URL. For example, in the URL
>   https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/e.-o.-wilsons-life-on-earth/id888107968?mt=13,
>   the asset ID is 888107968. A link to this book would be
>   ibooks://assetid/888107968.

One could implement it as such :

```
let stringURL = "ibooks://assetid/1219117996"
let url = URL(string:stringURL)
UIApplication.shared.open(url!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

I have yet to find a way to link to an iBook the user has manually imported.